# CSS3 and HTML5 div moving without JavaScript

Tags: html, css

Can I use just CSS3 and HTML5 to move a div or table by mouse in page without JavaScript?

I already do it but the div move automatically when hover move.

Answer (score 3):

You need JavaScript to do this. While you can program animations, transitions and the like in CSS3 which do provide animation to your web page components, you can't handle things like clicks and drags as you can in JavaScript.

It is worth noting that drag and drop functionailty *does* exist in HTML5, but not in the sense that I assume you want to implement.

Comment: :) ok tank you but you can give me link where i can learn it but by jqeury ?

Comment: You can go through html5 canvas tutorials.

Answer (score 1):

As shown here:

http://jsfiddle.net/yy2ak/

You can move the div using `CSS3 translate and transition`.  Or you could use `HTML5 draggable`.  However if you want something more dynamic then `JavaScript and jQuery` are your options.

To achieve this in `jQuery` you could do:

```
<div id="box" style="width: 50px; height: 50px; background-color: red;" />

$("#box").mouseover(function() {
   var offset = $(this).offset().left + 20;
    $(this).animate({
       left: offset
    }, 1000);
});
```